# How to get value from .ejs to javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, bookshelf.js

I have a .ejs file, which is actually a drop down form, that fills data using sqlite3 database. Now what i want to do is, when i select a value from dropdown, i want to send it back to my javascript file, where i'd save it to database.

Normally this wasn't hard on a select statement which i made on my own, but as this select statement gets filled from javascript, the value that sends back is **undefined**, don't know why.

To sum up on example:

I have a user that is logged in, and has option to save a workout on a dropdown.

**Workout table**

ID: 5

Name: Biceps

**Result**

**Exercise**

ID:1

Name: Biceps

Workout-ID: 5

**My code**

**Javascript to .ejs**

```
var Workout = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'workout'
});

var Exercise = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'exercise',
workout: function()
{
    return this.hasMany(Workout)
}
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
new Vaje().fetchAll().then(function (workout) {
    res.render('Exercise', { workout: workout });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
});
```

This sends all of the data from **workout** table into select form on .ejs

**.ejs file**

```
<h2>Select workout</h2>
<select>
<% workout.forEach(function(w) { %>
<option id=""
<%=w.attributes.id%>">
<%= w.attributes.name %>
</option>
<% }); %>
</select>
<br></br>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Add workout" />
</form>
```

**javascript file**

This file should now get selected value and save it to database...

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

var new_workout = req.body;

console.log("Workout: " + JSON.stringify(new_workout));

new Exercise().save(new_workout);
});
```

**Result from console**

[image]

I have no idea why the value is undefined/empty, but i would sure as hell like to find out.

Any help will be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE2**

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
new Vaje({ 'id': parseInt(req.body.naziv) })
    .fetch()
    .then(function (new_workout) {
        if (new_workout != null)
            new Trening().save({
                vaje_id: new_workout.get("id"),
                naziv: new_workout.get("naziv")
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your ejs file. You have Select out of your Form.

```
<h2>Select workout</h2>
<form method="post">

    <select name="workout">
        <% workout.forEach(function(w) { %>
            <option value="<%=w.attributes.id%>">
                <%= w.attributes.name %>
            </option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
    <br></br>

    <input type="submit" value="Add workout" />
</form>
```

**Edit 1**
Did you add to your application (for express 3).

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Its required to process post body.

**Edit 2 - solution for Express v.4**

first you need to install additional package

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

later edit your app:

```
var express = require('express'); // <- this is your code
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express(); // <- this is your code
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// and now app listen
app.listen(8888); // <- your port here
```

**Edit 3**

How to get Name & id. It will be something like this.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    new Workout({'id': parseInt(req.body.workout)})
        .fetch()
        .then(function(new_workout) {
            if(new_workout != null)
                new Exercise().save({
                    vaje_id: new_workout.get("id"),
                    name: new_workout.get("name")
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still says "Success" : undefined. Also a record is set to my datababe, but it is empty

Comment: edited my answer.. Did you add app.use(express.bodyParser()); to your app?

Comment: I should have asked it first.. Which version of express are you using ?

Comment: no i don't have it. i just addes it, but i get the "most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with express

...to be honest, i have no idea. i installed with via npm 2 days ago so probably the newest. if i go to npm list, it says express@4.13.4

Comment: i have this tho... app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: Maybe add name to the select field. If everything is in place it should be working.

Comment: your code is actually starting to work...i had a typo...i do get the name from the dropdown, but not the workout id. Can you please look at updated post and maybe suggest changes?

Comment: in option there should be value='' not id=''

Comment: You want name & id? If you want to do that you have 2 options. Get that name in your app by id, or write Javascript function which will post json from user.

Comment: yes that was kinda my question all the time as you can see from the result table...i know im starting to be kinda annoying, but any suggestions, links on how to do it? btw i'm still marking your question as solved because you did help me a lot..

Comment: no sadly it didn't. i will try to tweak the code myself :)

Comment: please see update... [note]i'm translating all of the variables from my native language to english, so console.log result may be consfusing because it says things like "treningi"

Comment: i have updated 'Edit 3'. I create new object from 'new_workout'. Chceck if it works

Comment: seems to be getting right id and name, but it is inserting id into wrong id...should'be on vaje_id ...please see update2 again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108400/discussion-between-bonanza-and-fokz8).

Comment: NOTE TO EVERYONE, solution is posted above. Thank you so much to kind sir Bonanza!